# href link to an element by id in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, materialize

i have a problem linking an element by Id using Google Apps Script. 
I'm using Materialize and in particular i want to use the tab structure.
I share with you my Code

```js
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul.tabs').tabs();
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul.tabs').tabs('select_tab', 'tab_id');
});



</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" width="device-width">
    <?!= include("RegLeague-css"); ?>
  </head>
  
  <body class='grey lighten-4'>

 
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <ul class="tabs">
     <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
     <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test2">Test2</a>     </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div id="test1" class="col s12">Test 1</div>
  <div id="test2" class="col s12">Test 2</div>
</div>
              
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"></script>
<?!= include("RegLeague-js"); ?>

</body>
 
</html>
```

Basically when I click on 1 link it doesn't redirect me to the id in the Html, but it link me to a site which is link/userCodeAppPanel#test1. I'm sure that is a problem with Google Apps Script because I tried the same code on Visual Studio and opened it with Live Server and it does work.

Could someone help me understand the problem, it should appear like in the picture below in the end

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLOfJ.png)

Comment: Could you explain why you have to initialisations for the tabs, and why the second one had two selectors?

Comment: And also two document.ready() - you should only have one, with all the code you need to wait inside.

Comment: If `I'm sure that is a problem with Google Apps Script because I tried the same code on Visual Studio and opened it with Live Server and it does work.`  your sure then report it as an issue.

Comment: What is `RegLeague-js`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line:

```html
<base target="_top">
```

In Apps Script Web Apps, in order to jump to other elements in the current page, you should be using `_self` instead:

```html
<base target="_self">
```

Or, since `_self` is the default value, get rid of the `target` attribute or even the `<base>` tag altogether.

#### Reference:

- [`<base>`: The Document Base URL element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)